# Passing extra arguments into objective function Nonconvex.jl

Tags: julia

I am working on implementing an optimizer using Nonconvex.jl and following this [example](https://julianonconvex.github.io/Nonconvex.jl/stable/#Quick-start). The description of objective function indicates that,

> The vector input to obj will be of the same structure, shape and types
> as the initial solution, lower bound and upper bound vector.

In my case I would like my objective function to calculate difference between model and measured values as RMS difference ([model - measured]^2). For this I need to pass the measured values to the objective function, just like one would do in [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy-optimize-minimize) with the help of **args** attribute.

So how do I send extra arguments to the objective function in Nonconvex.jl?

Comment: I've never used Nonconvex.jl, but... Is `measured` constant during minimization? If so, you may create a closure and pass it to the solver. `target(measured) = (model) -> norm(model - measured)`.

Comment: Thanks @StepanZakharov! Yes I am using closures for the implementation. Also, I did find Optimization.jl which provides the option of including parameters.